# MSc student in, of, and at

Tags: prepositions, vocabulary, in-of

I am a civil engineer and I'm a MSc student. I want to introduce myself. Which one will describe my position correctly?

- MSc student *in* civil engineering at ... University
- MSc student *of* civil engineering at ... University
- MSc civil engineering student at ... University

I'm not sure about using in/of/at.

Answer (score 2):

> MSc student *in* civil engineering at ... University

is correct since one gets a degree *in* a field of study.

Although you would be considered

> a student *of* civil engineering at ... University

Your last sentence

> MSc civil engineering student at ... University

is a headlinese form of the first, it is not correct but understandable.

Usually one would just say

> I am getting a masters in civil engineering *at* ... University

*At* is correct to show where you are getting your degree.